# Convert char array to integers

Tags: c, arrays, integer, char

I have a char array in the form of `mm/dd/yy` (as the user was asked to enter a date).

How do I split the array, and remove the `/`'s, and put `mm`, `dd` and `yy` into 3 different integers?

Comment: `strtol(3)` is probably the best function to start with.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would use sscanf to parse the string:

```
int m, d, y;    
sscanf("05/18/11", "%02d/%02d/%02d", &m, &d, &y);
```

This will parse the date into the three integer values.

In addition, to verify that the input data was formatted properly, you should also check that sscanf returned 3, indicating that all three values were properly parsed.  See the following [working example](http://codepad.org/25McwrMU), which includes some basic error checking.

Comment: You should include the error-checking from your linked code in your answer.

Answer (score 1):

Look into [`strtok`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstring/strtok/) and [`atoi`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdlib/atoi/) on the resulting tokens.

You could also use [`sscanf`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdio/sscanf/), but tokenizing provides more flexibility on the input format.

Comment: Please don't use atoi for parsing user input.  It has no way to detect errors.

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    int month, day, year;
    char mystr[10] = "05/18/11";
    month = atoi(strtok(mystr, "/"));
    day = atoi(strtok(NULL, "/"));
    year = atoi(strtok(NULL, "/"));
    return 0;
}
```

[strtok()](http://www.gnu.org/s/hello/manual/libc/Finding-Tokens-in-a-String.html) is a function that takes on first call a string and a delimiter to split on. After the first call, it will continue to tokenize the same string if you pass NULL as the first argument. `atoi` converts a string to an integer.

If your input is really rigid, sscanf is good.

Comment: Please don't use atoi for parsing user input.  It has no way to detect errors.

Answer (score -1):

First, locate the nearest `'/'`:

```
int i;
char *d = date;
for(i = 0; date[i] != '/'; ++i);
```

Then apply a "substring":

```
strncpy(dd, date, i);
```

Repeat this process:

```
d = date + i + 1;
for(; date[i] != '/'; ++i);
strncpy(mm, d, i - (d - date));
```

Then simply go from the last `'/'` to the end of the string:

```
d = date + i + 1;
strncpy(yy, d, strlen(date) - i);
```

Comment: The format of the OPs question was '/'. Had it been \, then you would have to use '\\'. The \ symbol has a special meaning inside C strings.

Comment: @downvoters I know I'm a bit late, but care to explain the downvote? (Other than being a bit less efficient than the above answers - I'm a C++ programmer.)